# Flow is defined using a $C^1$ function is $C^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems, gradient-flows

I have a flow defined by the initial value problem:

$$\frac{d}{dt}y_t(x)=f_t(y_t(x)), \quad y_0(x)=x$$

where $f_t:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$. I know the above problem has a unique solution for $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^k$, and I know that $f_t$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $x$. I have seen it claimed that these facts imply that $y_t$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $x$ but I don't see how this follows... please can someone show, or at least point me to a text showing, that $y_t$ must be continuously differentiable with respect to $x$?

Comment: This follows from continuous dependence on initial data from ODE theory

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean there. Please could you explain a bit further?

Comment: It's plausible because when you take the derivative of both sides of the ODE wrt $x$, you get an ODE for $D_xy_t(x)$, which has a solution. The proof is carried out here https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf

Comment: Apologies @Mason, this is probably a niave question; but which proof are you referring to in this book? I'm not as familiar with the notation they use

Comment: The section on differential equations proves the smoothness with respect to the initial condition.

Comment: Ah right! I see now - thank you @Mason! This answers my question.